# Assign specific resourcepool in a service block to specific agent? AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I have three sources each with different agents. I have assign three resource pool to service block. How do I specify which resource pool will work on which agent in that service block?

Answer (score 0):

Split the "Service" object into Seize+Delay+Release objects.

Use the "custom resource choice" option in your seize object and only seize resources as required by your agents.